# How do I make a chat message appear when a player joins my game

Tags: chat, roblox

So I have looked all over the web for a script that makes it so that when anyone joins my Roblox game it displays a message in chat (for example: "Player has joined my game"). This is the best that I've found:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
function onPlayerAdded((player)
     game:GetService("StarterGui"):SetCore("ChatMakeSystemMessage", {
        Text = "Welcome to my game!";
        Color = Color3.new(255/255, 0/255, 0/255);
        Font = Enum.Font.SourceSansLight;
        FontSize = Enum.FontSize.Size24;
    })
end)
```

My script is a LocalScript and it is in StarterGui.

If the question is unclear, I mean like in Minecraft when a player joins a server it usually says "Player joined the game", and I want that in my Roblox game.

Comment: What is your question? [Edit] your question and make it clear what about this code you need help with. See [ask].

Comment: I've edited your question to help improve the layout and grammar. I've also restored the script that you removed from your question as it helps us see what you're trying to do. If the edit is approved, you should see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the functionality of [StarterGui:SetCore()](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/StarterGui/SetCore).
Use the parameter "ChatMakeSystemMessage" with an array of Text, Color, Font and FontSize. Only Text is required in the array.

The following snippet will make a message in your (local) chat with the text "Hello World!".

```
game:GetService("StarterGui"):SetCore("ChatMakeSystemMessage", { Text ="Hello World!"})
```

Combine this with the game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded-event, and you've got yourself a new Welcome-message! 
Note that :SetCore() does not send the message to other players, so it only appears locally for each player.

Comment: Thanks, but if the player respawns, the player recives the message again.

Comment: @Gamer01 Where have you put the script?